# jQuery UI datepicker parseDate method does not parse 20140906

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the following code, however, the $.datepicker.parseDate method fails to parse `20140906` when I specify the format `yyMMdd`. How to parse this format in date picker?

```
function setValueDateRange(){
    if($("#businessDate").val()!=null && $("#businessDate").val()!='' && $("#businessDate").val()!='undefined'){
        var tillDateMin = $.datepicker.parseDate(GLOBAL_DATE_FORMAT,  $("#businessDate").val());
        tillDateMin.setDate(tillDateMin.getDate()+3);
        $("#paymentValueDateBatch").datepicker( "option", "minDate", tillDateMin);
    }

}

// GLOBAL_DATE_FORMAT-> yyMMdd
// $("#businessDate").val()->20140906
```

Comment: Looks like you accidentally submitted the question before you described the problem in detail.

Comment: The title should be a brief of the question, not the question itself.

Answer (score 6):

`$.datepicker.parseDate` parses a string, and returns a date object. Note that the [date format](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-parseDate) in the first argument tells parseDate how to parse the given date etc.

You're using `yyMMdd`, so it expects a date given like this

```
$.datepicker.parseDate('yyMMdd', '2014september06');
```

The month formats are as follows

- mm - month of year (two digit)
- M - month name short
- MM - month name
  long

Here's some valid examples

```
$.datepicker.parseDate('yymmdd', '20140906');
$.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', '06/09/2014');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eygsy0zb/3/)